# How to use 'limit' and 'start' properly (get the amount of number of instances)

Tags: graphql, strapi

I would like to fetch all the instances of a model but to use pagination to display them, so I would like to fetch 20 items on each page.

Fetching the first 20 items of the model would look like this:

```
const response = await strapi.request('POST', '/graphql', {
    data: {
        query: `query {
            exams (limit: 20, start: 0) {
              name,
              type
              _id,
            }
          }`
    }
})
```

The problem is that in order to create the functionality of the pagination, I would need to know in advance how many instances of the 'exam' model I have.

Does anyone know how to do this?

If it matters I'm using strapi cms with graphql plugin.

Comment: How your graphQL server connecting to database/data server?

Comment: You need to add one more field to your query to return total number of exams present, it will just be an extra field, which can be resolved by a field resolver.

Comment: I'm connecting through strapi cms and mlab
Pavan what would be that extra field?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the count feature.
Here is an example with **Restaurant** content type.

`./api/restaurant/config/schema.graphql.js`

```
module.exports = {
  definition: /* GraphQL */ `
    type RestaurantsConnection {
      aggregate: RestaurantsAggregate
    }
    type RestaurantsAggregate {
      count: Int
    }
  `,
  query: /* GraphQL */ `
    restaurantsConnection(where: JSON): RestaurantsConnection
  `,
  resolver: {
    Query: {
      restaurantsConnection(_, args) {
        return args;
      },
    },
    RestaurantsConnection: {
      aggregate(args) {
        return args;
      },
    },
    RestaurantsAggregate: {
      count(args) {
        return strapi.controllers.restaurant.count({
          query: args.where || {},
        });
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Now you have a connection to get count value

```
{
  restaurantsConnection {
    aggregate {
      count
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Strapi v4 pagination returns total number of records of content type

```
  query GetPhotosMeta {
    photos {
      __typename
      meta {
        __typename
        pagination {
          __typename              
          total
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/graphql-api.html#pagination